# How can I let JS UI building to field type plugin?

Tags: custom-fieldtype

I want to use like owl carousel JS UI in front.

Here's carousel [a link](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)!

It has some option can setting.

I want to create a own fields type in admin, can setting this option and show this UI in front view.

Answer (score 3):

You can quite easily set up asset and text fields to be fed into a owl-carousel template. Or you could create a matrix in which one of the blocks would automatically produce owl-carousel html and again pass asset and text fields in the matrix block to produce the images and captions.

If you want further assistances try to be a little more specific in your question.

Comment: thank you answer . let me further explan, i alrealy use matrix block but,owl-carousel setup in JS, I want  let JS parameters can edit in admin,  and matrix block not suitable ,how can i let it build like componemt

Comment: Still not completely sure what you're after, but to try and be slightly helpful, you may want to add fields to the matrix block which relay to a data object in the html which is then passed to the JS, i.e. a numbers field for the amount of slides you want per page, which is fed to a data-numbers object in the carousel html, and that then relays the slide number to the JS. That would be the simplest way to do (what I think) you want.